# How to convert old videos to a new format that is playable in most modern browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, video, vlc-media-player, codec

I found a stash of old video clips I'd like to share online with a HTML5-video player. But none of them opens in Chrome. I guess the codecs are not supported.

What format should I convert to? What is the recommended container and video/audio codec to use in 2022? I am using VLC (3.0.16) and the videos play nicely on my PC. But whatever combination of container/audio/video-codecs I try to convert to Chrome still won't play them. It would be nice to know what the preferred format and codecs to use...

Or should I not bother converting them like this but instead screen-capture them to a new video? Can VLC do that instead of converting? Or is that already what it does when I press "Convert/Save"?

---

This is a video that works fine to play:

[image: works.mp4]

And this video does not work:

[image: doesnotwork.avi]

Not even after converting it to this:

[image: doesnotwork.mp4]

Comment: What are they originally? Have you tried uploading one to YouTube to see if the problem is your player?

Comment: If VLC plays these videos, then VLC can also transcode them correctly to more modern formats. How are you doing the conversion? What format are these videos? To what format are you converting?

Comment: Seem to be a problem with mp4 without an audio track in Chrome. I have got it working with other converted videos now...